# Get logon information through ldap from AD server

Tags: active-directory, ldap, domain-controller, ad-lds

I want to know users logged into the domain and from which IP. I know it is possible to see by monitoring AD eventlogs. However, I want to do it without any software on AD server itself.
Is it possible to get that information by LDAP queries?

Answer (score 0):

Does a script count? I found one that will do the basic query and looping to get username and last login...you would still need to figure out the attribute for the last login IP address though.

Here is the [script home (vb script and powershell versions)](http://www.rlmueller.net/GenericADO.htm) and a [Discussion of use](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/414a5d52-59a7-46a4-bd28-590b94d22665/). You can edit the script to target a specific DC instead of the directory as a whole.